# How can I write to a vector with one process and read it with another without performance loss

Tags: c++, multithreading, ipc

I have a vector that is constantly being updated (about 5-20 times a second) with new information by a process that I wrote to gather the information.  I want to write a loop that would be able to detect a change in the vector, and then read the information and do the appropriate analysis that I write for that event.  However, I know that there are many issues that arise from multithreading like this, so I'm curious what the best ways to do something like this are.

The vector is stored in a public class and is being updated by a feed we get from a financial company (the information being updated is futures indices).

Comment: To clear up some confusion, can you explain your architecture a little more? Is this a single process with multithreading, or multiple processes?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was multiple processes.  That's my bad.

Comment: It's usually (but not always) more trouble than it's worth to share data structures between processes. You might be better off for example having your gathering process write a series of changes to its own standard output, then your analysis process reads them. That way you turn a problem with interprocess data-sharing into a problem with ensuring that the gathering process never ends up blocked because its stdout buffer is full. Still not trivial, but usually an easier problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the feed data asynchronously using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Comment: Have you thought about how you would implement the IPC (inter-process communication) (shared mem, raw TCP/IP, named pipes, stdout, COM, CORBA, etc...)?  This will most likely affect how you would implement your reading/writing the data to your shared structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this in C++. If you used shared memory you could store the `vector` in it, but its components would still be pointing at local, non-shared memory chunks, preventing it from being shared (you *might* be able to work around with with allocator trickery but I'm not sure it would work).

`boost` has some shared memory capabilities but as I recall from a question I can't find it has some downsides. You'll most likely have to design your own shared memory data structure and provide a mechanism to store a condition variable there so clients can wait on it to determine when new data is available.

EDIT: I found the question asking about `boost::interprocess`:

[Is boost::interprocess ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196395/is-boostinterprocess-ready-for-prime-time)

Comment: As usual, `boost` to the rescue ;)  There are interprocess containers as well as synchronization primatives. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/vector.html

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but in such a case, I would suggest changing the design: make the vector private, add a Setter function (wrapping push_back() or other) that will be used by your data feed, and youre done.
Or did I miss something ?

Comment: I think you missed that the data is being read by a *separate* process.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP really has separate processes. I think he means threads...

Comment: He has confirmed he means processes.